# How to get the string from the current iterator position?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a string and I want to iterate in the string, then I want to get the string from an iterator pos to call stoi, I don't know if I'm being clear enough, here's the code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cctype>
# include <stack>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) { std::cerr << "Usage: ./a.out <expression>" << std::endl; return (-1); }

    std::stack<int> numbers;
    std::string expr(argv[1]);
    for (auto it = expr.begin(); it != expr.end(); it++)
        if (std::isdigit(*it))
        {
            numbers.push(std::stoi(/*string from it*/));
            while (std::isdigit(*it)) it++;
        }
    while (!numbers.empty())
        std::cout << numbers.top() << std::endl, numbers.pop();
    return (0);
}
```

I know I can just use an index but I want to do it the iterator C++ friendly way. Thanks for your help
For example: ./a.out "hello543   29786++23839 kek22"
should output:

```
543
29786
23839
22
```

Comment: Iterator is a pointer to a single char of the string, what you want? you want a string from start to that `it` position to which it is currently pointing?

Comment: @foragerDev No I want the opposite, a string from it position to end

Comment: `std::isdigit()` takes a `char`, not a string.

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA I know that, I'm using isdigit to check if the current char is digit then call stoi or atoi

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you would input and what ouput you would expect from the code? Hopefully, we would understand more

Comment: @Fayeure your question is not really clear.

Comment: I added example output

Comment: There's nothing wrong (or unfriendly) with using an index. Much of the `std::string` API uses indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You want the address of the element. You do it like this:

```
std::stoi(&*it);
```

On that note, you don't need to construct a `std::string` from `char*` then use iterators, then convert the iterator back to a `char*`. You could just use a `char*` and it'd probably be cleaner:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: ./a.out <expression>\n";
    return -1;
  }

  std::stack<int> numbers;
  char const* str = argv[1];
  while (*str) {
    if (std::isdigit(*str)) {
      char* end;
      numbers.push(std::strtol(str, &end, 10)); // note strol
      str = end;
    } else
      ++str;
  }

  while (!numbers.empty()) {
    std::cout << numbers.top() << '\n';
    numbers.pop();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition.
The parsing of the command line argument in the loop is accessing elements with string iterator.
The inverse display of a stack is done by a fucntion `printStack(std::stack<int>)`

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <cctype>
# include <stack>
# include <vector>
# include <sstream>
# include <iterator>

void PrintStack(std::stack<int> s);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./a.out <expression>" << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }

    std::stack<int> numbers;
    //std::string expr(argv[1]);
    std::vector<std::string> expr(argv+1, argv + argc);

    for (auto it = expr.begin(); it != expr.end(); it++)
    {
        //cout <<"****" << *it;
        std::string the_num="";
        // extract the number part of each elements
        for (auto iter =it->begin(); iter != it->end(); iter++)
        {
            // now we have characters
            if (std::isdigit(*iter))
            {
                //cout << "$" << *iter<<endl;
                std::string s(1, *iter);
                the_num += *iter;
            }
            else
            {
                if (the_num != "")
                {
                    numbers.push(stoi(the_num));
                    the_num="";
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
        if (the_num != "")
        {
            numbers.push(stoi(the_num));
            the_num="";
        }
        the_num="";
    }

    PrintStack(numbers);


    return (0);
}

void PrintStack(std::stack<int> s)
{
    // If stack is empty then return
    if (s.empty())
        return;

    int x = s.top();
    // Pop the top element of the stack
    s.pop();
    // Recursively call the function PrintStack
    PrintStack(s);
    // Print the stack element starting
    // from the bottom
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    // Push the same element onto the stack
    // to preserve the order
    s.push(x);
}
```

Execution with your examples, gives the following:

```sh
./find_str hello543 29786++23839 kek22
543
29786
23839
22
```